# requirejs-config, requirejs errors

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, bug, magento2.2.3

Does anyone know where these errors come from and how to solve them !

> Failed to load for  element whose source is
>   `http://...pub/static/version1521024130/frontend.../fr_FR/text.js`

[image]

I also see this in **logs**:

> main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'requirejs-config' element cannot be
>   added as child to 'head', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>
> main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'requirejs' element cannot be added
>   as child to 'head', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>
> main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'requirejs-config' tries to reorder
>   itself towards 'requirejs', but their parents are different: 'head'
>   and '' respectively. [] []
>
> main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for
>   'frontend/Smt/theme/fr_FR/text.js' [] []

Info: Im in `developer mode`, I deployed the `static-content`, `clean cache`, `pub/static`, `var/view_preprocessed`, `generated` but always the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you make any changes to the `<head>` section of the theme?
2. How did you delare the `text.js` file?
3. Don't use `setup:static-content:deploy` in Developer mode, in Developer mode you have symlinks for the files in your theme

Comment: 1. I added some css files in `head`, but i tried to disable the theme and set another one, the result is the same (same errors) 2. `text.js` i declared it any where ! the file is well available in `lib/web/requirejs/text.js` 3. I know that deploying static-contents is not necessary in dev mode, but i forced it to look if these errors comes from that

Comment: @Prince do you have any custom JS or something custom functionality done in JS files?

Comment: Yes, I have....